# Clone function in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, copy, clone

I am trying to implement a virtual function that is in a .h file in my .cpp file. This is for an assignment, so I cannot just make the function non-virtual. This is a clone function, which invokes the class's copy constructor. The function:

```
virtual Item* clone() const;
```

is in the class

```
Ingredient : public Item {
```

When I implement it in my Ingredient.cpp file, I have:

```
Ingredient::clone () const {
    return new Ingredient ( *this );
}
```

But when I try to compile, I get these two errors:

Ingredient.cpp:23:13: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations

```
Ingredient::clone () const {
        ^
```

Ingredient.cpp:24:9: error: cannot initialize return object of type 'int' with an rvalue of type 'Ingredient *'

```
    return new Ingredient ( *this );
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

2 errors generated.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here, because I am supposed to be making use of the dereferenced *this self pointer. Any suggestions?

Comment: Missing return type in function signature.. http://ideone.com/J0U8wv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the return type in the function implementation.

```
Item* Ingredient::clone () const {
// ^^ Missing
```

Comment: Something so simple...but that was the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @camcovington, you are welcome.

Comment: Why using the `return new Ingredient ( *this );` here instead of the `return *this` or `return new Ingredient()` ?

Comment: `return *this;` will be a compiler since the return type and the returned value won't match. `return new Ingredient()` is not correct since the function is expected to clone the current object, not return an unrelated object.